# Finding the position of edge defects of a circular object with MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have a problem finding defects at the edge of a circular object. It's hard to describe so I have a picture which may help a bit.  I am trying to find the red marked areas, such as what is shown below:

[image: I try to find the red marked areas. In this picture]

I already tried matching with templates `vision.TemplateMatcher()`, but this only works well for the picture I made the template of.

I tried to match it with `vision.CascadeObjectDetector()` and I trained it with 150 images. I found only < 5% correct results with this.

I also tried matching with `detectSURFFeatures()` and then `matchFeatures()`, but this only works on quite similar defects (when the edges are not closed it fails).

Since the defects are close to the half of a circle, I tried to find it with `imfindcircles()`, but there I find so many possible results. When I take the one with the highest metric sometimes I get the right one but not even close to 30%.

Do any of you have an idea what I can try to find at least more than 50%?

If someone has an idea and wants to try something I added another picture.
Since I am new I can only add two pictures but if you need more I can provide more pictures.

[image]

[image: Object before edge detection]
[image: Object after edge detection]

Comment: There are other gaps in the example image that you didn't mark.  Are those not flaws as well?  BTW, I have to applaud you for trying a lot of ideas. Even though the code you wrote is not there, you have exhausted almost every possibility. Have a vote from me.

Comment: Maybe you should start with describing what that "edge defect" is. Because I see lots of defects. What is the original image? Maybe you can improve previous steps first?

Comment: Thanks for your fast responds. The red marked defekt, is a mark for a disc like object which is for the alignment during some processes. I have added two new images one is before a used edge(Image,'log',0); and the last one is the Image of the detected edges. The only previous steps I have is cutting out the object and removing the inner part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to detect rough edges like that on smooth binary overlays as you provided before? For eg. are you making a program whose input consists of getting a black image with lots of circles with rough edges which its then supposed to detect? i.e. sudden rough discontinuities in a normally very smooth region.

If the above position is valid, then this may be solved via classical signal processing. My opinion, plot a graph of the intensity on a line between any two points outside and inside the circle. It should look like

```
  .. continuous constant ... continuous constant .. continuous constant.. DISCONTINUOUS VARYING!! DISCONTINUOUS VARYING!! DISCONTINUOUS VARYING!! ... continuous constant .. continuous constant..
```

Write your own function to detect these discontinuities.

OR

Gradient: The rate of change of certain quantities w.r.t a distance measure.

Use the very famous Sobel (gradient) filter.

Use the X axis version of the filter, See result, if gives you something detectable use it, do same for Y axis version of filter.

In case you're wondering, if you're using Matlab then you just need to get a readily available and highly mentioned 3x3 matrix (seen almost everywhere on the internet ) and plug it into the imfilter function, or use the in-built implementation (edge(image,'sobel')) (if you have the required toolbox).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try if this will lead to a solution for my problem.